# Contact List View - Get Related

Tags: contact, list-view, mass-email

I have a custom field (lookup) on Account that links Accounts to Contacts. It's called 'Clerk__c' indicating that the contact is a clerk for the account.

I want to "mass mail" all clerks, so I would like to generate a list view on Contacts that has only those contacts named as a clerk on the account.

I can't figure out how to generate this list view. Is it possible?

Comment: Add a number field to Contact called something line `AccountsWhereClerkCount` and populate it from an Account trigger? Then filter on that being greater than zero.

Comment: @KeithC yeah that's a solution I was trying to avoid!

Comment: Yeah pretty ugly for such a small thing. Rollups on master-detail are really convenient for this kind of thing.

Comment: You could use Andrew Fawcett's Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary to build the RSF field across the lookup relationship as @KeithC suggests without having to code the trigger. DLRS is free and is all point-and-click